# PKCS1_PSS sign() method

Tags: python, digital-signature, signature, pycrypto

I have been trying to fix an issue but failed countless times. I need to use a method, sign(), and I have the correct library imported, however its still not being recognized.

I'm coding in Python and this is what I have that seems important:

```
#importing the library
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_PSS

[...]
signer = PKCS1_PSS.new(keypair)
sig = PKCS1_PSS.sign(keypair)
```

But the sign() method is the only thing in the entire code from that library that doesn't get recognized:

> "This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to
>   dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but
>   useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported
>   better than instance items."

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of [PKCS1_PSS](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_PSS-module.html) is wrong. It currently says:

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_PSS
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

message = 'To be signed'
key = RSA.importKey(open('privkey.der').read())
h = SHA.new()
h.update(message)
signer = PKCS1_PSS.new(key)
signature = PKCS1_PSS.sign(key)
```

But it should be the following analogous to the documentation of [PKCS1_v1_5](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html)

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_PSS
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

message = 'To be signed'
key = RSA.importKey(open('privkey.der').read())
h = SHA.new()
h.update(message)
signer = PKCS1_PSS.new(key)
signature = signer.sign(h)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ^^